# Complex objects at settings. Serializing issue

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Default settings serializer supports only simple types. How should I save complex classes. For example:

```
public class User
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have to save each field of complex object as separate setting to make it work.
Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take a look to Generic Object Storage Helper for WinRT, available at http://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com.

This library serializes your objects using XML format.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. Actually I prefer json to xml and will try to optimize this solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to serialize your settings object and store it as a string. I would recommend JSON.Net for doing this.

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mySettings);
// do something with this string
```

You can then create a new object from the json

```
MySettingsObject mySettings = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MySettingsObject>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree that this is the easiest one but it lacks some flexibility for subsequent update when settings names and type could be changed.